# LUA: how do you save someones progress?

Tags: lua

lets say you have a script like this

```lua
print("you've been here for the first time.")
print("you're here for second or more time")
```

how would you make it so once a person runs the script once, instead of repeating the whole script it just goes to the second print right away?

Comment: You have to read/write from/to a log file that contains how many times the script is run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically need to:

- Save the state of the program when the program ends
- Restore the state of the program when the program starts

There are several ways to store the state, the simplest way would be to create a file and store the state inside. One could also use the Windows Registry, a database, a remote server, etc.

A simple example:

```
function FileExists (Filename)
  local File = io.open(Filename, "r")
  if File then
    File:close()
  end
  return File
end

function CreateFile (Filename)
  local File = io.open(Filename, "w")
  if File then
    File:close()
  end
end

ProgramStateFile = "program-state.txt"

if not FileExists(ProgramStateFile) then
  print("you've been here for the first time.")
else
  print("you're here for second or more time")
end

CreateFile(ProgramStateFile)
```

In this example, the state is only the existence of the state file. Obviously, you can extend this example by writing additional information inside the file.

```
function ReadState (Filename)
  local File = io.open(Filename, "r")
  local State
  if File then
    State = File:read("a")
    File:close()
  end
  return State
end

function WriteState (Filename, State)
  local File = io.open(Filename, "w")
  if File then
    File:write(State)
    File:close()
  end
end

ProgramStateFile = "program-state.txt"

if ReadState(ProgramStateFile) ~= "PROGRAM-FINISHED" then
  print("you've been here for the first time.")
else
  print("you're here for second or more time")
end

WriteState(ProgramStateFile, "PROGRAM-FINISHED")
```

Finally, please note that there are many formats already existing to store the states: INI file, XML, JSON, etc. For Lua, you could also use a serialization library in order to store a Lua table directly inside a file. I would personally recommend the [binser library](https://github.com/bakpakin/binser).